# Material UI Autocomplete - Search only from the beginning of the word

Tags: reactjs, search, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm using material UI Autocomplete field in my React application and I want the search in it to work only from the beginning of the keyword (for some fields of the objects):

For example, if the options are

```
[
  {data1:'abc', data2:'a123'},
  {data1:'cba', data2:'345'},
  {data1:'bca3', data2:'654'}
]
```

and I type `a` - only the first option should appear.
If I type `3` - only the second option should appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made it work with `filterOptions` Autocomplete prop and `'match-sorter'` library:

```
const filterOptions = (options,{ inputValue }) =>
    matchSorter(options, inputValue, {
      keys: [
        { threshold: matchSorter.rankings.STARTS_WITH, key: 'data1' },
        { threshold: matchSorter.rankings.STARTS_WITH, key: 'data2' },
        'data3',
      ],
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add some extra infos about filtering. You can also use the `createFilterOptions` provided from the MUI Autocomplete.

Example:

```
import { createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
  matchFrom: 'start',
  stringify: option => option.title,
});

<Autocomplete filterOptions={filterOptions} />
```

You can set some optional filters:

- ignoreAccents (Boolean [optional])
- ignoreCase (Boolean [optional])
- limit (Number [optional])
- matchFrom ('any' | 'start' [optional])
- stringify (Func [optional])
- trim (Boolean [optional])

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

Hope this could help someone!

Answer (score -1):

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values

It works,
You need to add
multiple

```
  <Autocomplete
    multiple
    id="tags-standard"
    options={top100Films}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
    defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
    renderInput={params => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        variant="standard"
        label="Multiple values"
        placeholder="Favorites"
      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: I don't need multiple values in my field tho.  I need a search to be through each object fields